# It is possible for iPhone Apps to automatically download XML files?

Tags: iphone, xml, web-applications

Like the topic title mentioned. I'm trying to make an app (for iPhone) that will automatically update itself based on the modifications done to XML but am unsure on how to go about it.

I'm torn between creating a web-based app and a real app for a particular project that keeps track of events happening in a country, so any tips regarding these two different methods are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is enough information to answer this. Both types of applications are able to read and parse XML. It depends on the kind of updates you are talking about. If it is of any help, native apps are always more powerful.

Comment: Create a web-based app, and any modification in XML on server side will be reflected back in your app if you use random string at the end of each webservice call in your iphone side code.

Comment: I'm trying to create an app that displays the latest information of the events that is happening in a particular country/city. For example, a garage sales events of sorts.

I'm not exactly familiar in the parsing of XML online, so I was thinking that if it's possible for my iPhone app to download the latest version of an XML and then parse it within the app itself...

Or the other method is to make a website with mobile support, then I don't have to bother with XML and just update from the website itself...

Anymore help/tips regarding this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
```

targetmethod is your method to read xml and update your page after that.
repeat yes if you want to repeat it again and again
repeat NO if you want to execute it once.
scheduledTimerWithInterval:1.0   represents 1 second.
change it to 30 for 30 seconds or 120 for 2 minutes.

i dont know how to create web based application, but i know how to parse xml data. Let me know if you need any information
 on xml parsing.

Comment: Ah, I remember this NSTimer functionality. I used it in a game I made for iPhone. The thing is, I would love to know how to use XML to achieve the desired results. I'm a complete newbie when it comes to XML and any help for that (or any tutorials) would be extremely helpful and appreciated!

Comment: i have used NSXMLParser, it is very easy to use. http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/make-nsxmlparser-your-friend.html  check this tutorial. And also check NSXMLParserDelegate methods

Comment: Thanks, I'll bookmark that and read it up as soon as I can. It is possible for one to parse a URL in and allow the app to load an image based on the link provided? So far I've only done offline image pointing, never really tried online...

Comment: and one more thing if you are satisfied with my answer or iphoneplayer's answer, then accept my or his answer.

Comment: Something like the XML file having <element>http://domain.com/image.png</element> and then having the iPhone display the image based on the link provided in the element...

Comment: ok so you want to read a url or any data between element tag or any tag. So you need to parse XML. you can use NSXMLParser class. check that link if you are not satisfied google it. its easy just create an instance of NSXMLParser set delegate and use delegate methods.

Comment: implement at least 2 delegate methods didstartelement and foundCharacters. Now you can read data in two ways, suppose you have total three tags in your xml file <element>, <element1> and <element2> and you want data from element tag only. In didstartelement check the current element if it is "element" set a flag(flag=1 or anything else) now check flag in foundCharacters method if(flag==1) store the string in an array or append it to a string(whatever you want to do).

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to update contents of your screen like stock price in stock market app.
you can do this with the help of a timer (check NSTimer).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've used NSTimer sparingly during my time in Objective-C (i'm relatively new to ObjC) and I can't picture on how to use NSTimer to help me achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a web-based app, and any modification in XML on server side will be reflected back in your app if you use random string at the end of each webservice call in your iphone side code.